# Resolving <NSManagedObject: 0x155ec810> (entity: EventDetails; id:some id /EventDetails/p1> ; data: <fault>)"

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How to resolve this issue. 
**" (entity: EventDetails; id: 0x155ebe90  ; data: )"**.

I am using below piece of code to fetch events from my entity.

```
 managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] parentContext];
    writerObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;

    [temporaryContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        if (temporaryContext == nil) {

            managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] parentContext];
            writerObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            temporaryContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;

        }
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EventDetails"];


        NSArray *arr = [temporaryContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSLog(@" %@", arr);

        if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error in getsize - error:%@",[error userInfo]);
        }


        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

            NSError *error = nil;

            if(![managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }

            [writerObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

                NSError *error = nil;

                if(![writerObjectContext save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"error");
                }

            }]; // writer
        }]; // main
    }]; // parent
```

I runned above code both on my iphone and simulator.But getting same result. How to get rid of this?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having. Where does that text in quotes come from? What did you expect to be different?

Answer (score 0):

`data: <fault>` (presumably from a log statement) simply means that Core Data did not fetch all the associated data from the database but will make future trips to the store automatically, should the information be needed.

In other words, this is normal behavior. You do not need to worry about it.

Comment: Although there is no "action item" in this solution, you should still accept the answer for the benefit of other users.